# RTCDataChannel.send Firefox problems

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I'm doing some tests with WebRTC technology, but I have some problems with RTCDataChannel between Chrome and Firefox. The connection works fine and I can send data between the two browsers, but the problems comes when one of two disconnects.

When Chrome is sending data and Firefox receiving data and Firefox disconnects, channel in Chrome side set its readyState to close, and I can handle this showing a message.

When Firefox is sending data and Chrome receiving data and Chrome disconnects, channel in Firefox side **NOT CHANGES ITS readyState**, so I can't handle this and apparently Firefox continues sending data to a ¿closed channel?

My code is easy:

To stablish connection:

```
[...]
if(offerer){
        channel = connection.createDataChannel("dataChannel", null);
        setChannelEvents(channel);
        connection.createOffer(myFunc, showError);
}else{
        connection.ondatachannel = function(event){
           channel = event.channel;
           setChannelEvents(channel);
        }
    }
[...]
```

When connection is stablished and can send messages:

```
[...]
try{
  channel.send(message);
    }catch(e){
        //handle error here
        [...]
    }
[...]
```

As I said, when in Chrome channel.send(message); returns error (because readyState is setted to close and can't send message) the code in 'handle error here' executes, but in Firefox never executes.

Can somebody help me please? It's a bit frustrating.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try my code:

```
switch (channel.readyState) {
case 'open':
    channel.send(message);
    break;
case 'closed':
    console.log('channel.readyState = ' + channel.readyState);
    //handle error here
    break;
default:
    console.error('channel.readyState = ' + channel.readyState);
```

}

I has successfully tested in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I tried your code but not working. My problem is that channel.readyState is always 'open' even when the other user close the channel. So, the execution enters always in "case 'open'" :(

Comment: Currently I use Windows 10, Firefox 46.0.1 and Chrome 51.0.2704.63. Please tell me your OS version and browsers versions

Comment: I'm using Mac OSX El Capitan with Chrome 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit) and Firefox 46.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Call [RTCDataChannel.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/close) method on the receiver side.

Comment: Currently close method is called by receiver, the problem is that the sender does not know that the channel is closed, because his readyState var is always in 'open' :(

Comment: I do not have any ideas :( Please inform me if you have resloved your problem